# Magento 2 authorize.net credit card validation issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, authorize.net

In magento 2.3.2 i have checked and found one issue regarding credit card validation in authorize.net on onestepcheckout or normal checkout page,I have debug and find if we merge js at that time issue is generated,Here are screenshot of both scenario

[image]

Its working before js merge

[image]

Comment: Please you go to authorize account and find price filter decrease and after check

Comment: Hello @MohitPatel its working fine if we not merge js. thank you for response.